# Set wysiwyg's value with javascript

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

How do I set a WYSIWYG's value with javascript? does the [WYSIWYG](https://drupal.org/project/WYSIWYG) module provide an api for this?

I don't know which editor user is using, so I can't use the api of editors.

Comment: by WYSIWYG's value you mean the content of the textarea?

Comment: @jonhattan Yes!

Comment: You don't want to hook on `hook_form_alter` I guess ?

Comment: @GregoryKapustin Content should be inserted by javascript

Comment: Any reason why you want the content to be inserted by JavaScript?

Comment: @Randell I have a form in which a set of nodes are listed. Users can update content of the nodes directly from the from, without refreshing the page or going to the node edit form page. So I need javascript to load a node's content when it's title is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked perfectly fine for me,

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#edit-body-und-0-value").val('this is a test content.');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have placed this code is test.js file. 'edit-body-und-0-value' is the ID of the textarea.

I have installed WYSIWYG module and placed CKEditor under sites/all/libraries/ckeditor folder. Although it doesn't matter if you are using CKEditor or any other editor because we are mainly referring to ID of our textarea.